# How to get Private Key from Smartcard in Reader using Chilkat

Tags: jks, chilkat

Im using Chilkat/ck-node12-win64 from Node.js, and i want to know how can i get the private key from Smartcard in Reader (or from USB Token) ?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The whole purpose of a smart card or usb token is that the private key stays on the hardware and cannot be accessed.  The signing must occur on the smart card.